# NestJs Jest Unit Test Failed - toHaveBeenCalled even though it is called

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have an issue with my unit test in my `NestJs` program. I am using `Jest` for the unit test, I have created a mocking method that is called, but `Jest` thinks otherwise.
I couldn't find the solution to this problemn using **NestJs**.

The test file `themes.service.spec.ts`:

```
...
  /* Mock of Repository */
  const mockThemesRepository = {
    findOne: jest.fn().mockImplementation(id => {
      return {id: id}
    }),
    remove: jest.fn().mockImplementation(dto => {
      console.log("MESSAGE 2") // printed
      console.log(dto) // printed
      return {
        dto
      }
    })
  }

  /* Inject the mock object */
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ThemesService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Theme),
          useValue: mockThemesRepository,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<ThemesService>(ThemesService);
  });

  /* Test Remove method */
  it('should delete a theme', async () => {
    service.remove(1)

    expect(mockThemesRepository.findOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
    expect(mockThemesRepository.remove).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
...
```

The service file: `themes.service.ts`:

```
...
export class ThemesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Theme)
    private readonly themeRepository: Repository<Theme>
  ) {}
...

  async remove(id: number): Promise<Theme> {
    const theme = await this.themeRepository.findOne(id);
    console.log("MESSAGE 1"); // printed
    return this.themeRepository.remove(theme);
  }
}
```

- The error message:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0

  103 |     expect(mockThemesRepository.findOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
> 104 |     expect(mockThemesRepository.remove).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

### The test is called but Jest think it wasn't.

## EDIT:

With the solution proposed by `Jay McDoniel`, the test works:

```
    expect(mockThemesRepository.findOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
    expect(await mockThemesRepository.remove).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: If you `await service.remove()` does it fix the problem?

Comment: Do you want to write a answer or should I do it?